# javascript, animate and fadeout together

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, fadeout

I need to animate an image and fade it out at the same time.
The image is situated in the right of the page, I need to move it to the left and fade it out so that when it reaches the left it is totally disappeared. I tried to combine .fadeOut and .animate (see example below) but actually the image moves, stops and then fadeout. Can you help me?

```
<script>
$("#link").click(function() { 
$("#image").animate({ 
marginLeft: "-1000px"
}, 1500).fadeOut(1600); 
}); 
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the opacity of the element. By settings this to zero, the element will fadeout to the duration of the animation.

**Code:**

```
$('#link').click(function() { 

  $('#image').animate({ 
    marginLeft: '-100px',
    opacity: 0
  }, 1500); 

});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QqfLL/

Answer (score 0):

Set `opacity` of `#image` to 0 and try this :

```
$("#link").click(function() { 
$("#image").animate({ 
marginLeft: "-1000px",
opacity: 1
}, 1500); 
});
```

You will have to check if this work correctly in IE.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly also in IE. Can you help me in another step of this case?

Summarizing, in the center of the screen there is a div, and below there are a few links. Each link, when clicked, must show in the div a different image. When a link is clicked, the current image must move to the left and fadeout, at the same time the new image must appear from the right with fading and place itself in the div.

Can you help me?

Comment: @maurice77 : If it's ok, mark answer as Accepted, and ask a new question for your second problem